# How to extract Zlib from JPG

Tags: jpeg, zlib, ctf

I'm currently doing a forensics CTF challenge, where the flag is hidden inside a .jpg file. When I do binwalk on the file, I see the following:

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
34650         0x875A          PNG image, 600 x 424, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
34749         0x87BD          Zlib compressed data, best compression
353954        0x566A2         JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
```

I want to check out the contents of the Zlib file, but can't figure out how to extract it successfully.
Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried?  In the programming language of your choice, use a zlib library after extracting the zlib section from the file?

Comment: The zlib compressed data is very likely part of the PNG image. It is not a "file". Since you have the offset, you just use zlib's `uncompress()` or `inflate()` starting there. What have you tried? What language are you using?